# Angular2 build application for production does not include all files

Tags: angular, build, npm, webpack

I'm trying to build Angular2 application, to have it optimized, and not all files are included.

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    templateUrl: '../../html/app.html',
    styleUrls: ['../../css/components/app.css'] 
})

export class AppComponent {}
```

**app.html**

```
<div class="logo">
<img src="img/image.png" alt=""></a>
</div>

<div class="video-container">
<video width="100%" controls>
<source src="video/video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
</div>
```

After run:

```
npm run build
```

My Angular2 application is compiled in `/dist` directory

```
/assets
app.css
app.css.map
app.js
app.js.map
index.html
polyfils.js
polyfils.js.map
vendor.js
vendor.js.map
```

As we can see in template file are two sources: "img/image.png" and "video/video.mp4". After build my `image.png` file is in `/assets` directory, but the `video.mp4` file is not. I need to put `video/video.mp4` in `/dist` directory manually, because without of that I've got 404 errors "file not found" after run `$ lite-server`.

I can also see differences in `app.js.map` file:

```
<img src=\\\"\" + __webpack_require__(107)
...
<source src=\\\"video/video.mp4
```

### My question is, how to force build module to include all types of files? Is it possible? I assume that something can be wrong with my webpack configuration.

**package.json** fragment:

```
{...
  "scripts": {
    "start": "webpack-dev-server --inline --progress --port 8080 --display-error-details",
    "build": "rimraf dist && webpack --config config/webpack.prod.js --progress --profile --bail"
  }
...
}
```

**webpack.prod.js**

```
var webpack = require('webpack');
var webpackMerge = require('webpack-merge');
var ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
var commonConfig = require('./webpack.common.js');
var helpers = require('./helpers');

const ENV = process.env.NODE_ENV = process.env.ENV = 'production';

module.exports = webpackMerge(commonConfig, {
  devtool: 'source-map',

  output: {
    path: helpers.root('dist'),
    publicPath: '/',
    filename: '[name].[hash].js',
    chunkFilename: '[id].[hash].chunk.js'
  },

  htmlLoader: {
    minimize: false // workaround for ng2
  },

  plugins: [
    new webpack.NoErrorsPlugin(),
    new webpack.optimize.DedupePlugin(),
    new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
      mangle: {
        keep_fnames: true
      }
    }),
    new ExtractTextPlugin('[name].[hash].css'),
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      'process.env': {
        'ENV': JSON.stringify(ENV)
      }
    })
  ]
});
```